# Error on file open: File exists

Tags: c, linux, file-io, errno

The return value of an open() was -1 and on trying to find the error using perror() the output was "File exists".

How do I find the error or the reason for the file not opening.

Comment: Well, it seems you've found the reason why it fails, so... what's exactly your question?

Comment: Please post the code you use in your `open` call. Chances are you're using options incompatible with opening an existing file.

Comment: agree with Mat...post your fopen sentence

Comment: Please post the call to `open()`, or this question will quickly be closed.

Comment: @Tim Sorry about not posting the code. Got my answer..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like

> EEXIST
>       pathname already exists and O_CREAT and O_EXCL were used.

Answer (score -4):

You probably would have given the macro with the quotes as described below:

> fd = open(filename,"O_RDONLY" );

It should be `fd = open(filename,O_RDONLY);` without quotes.

Comment: -1: This is pure guessing - and the appropriate code you suggest might even not compile.