# Negative return value in open system call for file created in /proc file system

Tags: c, file, procfs

I have created a file in `/proc` named "test" (it was created in kernel). The file exists. When I want to open it in user level it returns negative.

```
int fd;
if((fd=open("/proc/test","O_RDONLY"))<0){ 
      perror("open"); 
}
```

The error that I see is `open: File exists`. I have seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7390674/error-on-file-open-file-exists) but it is not my case.

Comment: you are not allowed to create, run your code as: `sudo ./your_code`

Comment: Thanks but still same error.

Comment: you got an answer below :)

Comment: I can't even parse the headline of this question, can you please take a bit more care when you post here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need parentheses in there (now fixed in the question), and the second argument to [`open()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/open.html) is not a string:

```
#include <fcntl.h>

int fd;
if ((fd = open("/proc/test", O_RDONLY)) < 0)
    perror("open");
```

I'm not convinced it was a good idea to create a file of any sort in the `/proc` file system. In fact, I'm a bit surprised you were allowed to.  If you are learning to program as `root`, I hope you have good backups.

Comment: After doing like above it says: O_RDONLY undeclared. I have included <unistd.h>

Comment: It is hard to help you accurately if you don't show the code you've got problems with accurately.  But the second argument should not be a quoted string (`fopen()` takes a string for its second argument; `open()` does not).  And are you running as root?  And what are the permissions on `/proc/test`?  Look at the link I gave you; it is `#include <fcntl.h>` for `open()`.

Comment: @sweet I think you need to read some tutorials. These are very basic, beginner questions that could be answered by any decent tutorial or book.

Comment: I have compile error after removing quote from second argument.